# Parser JSON not responding as it should respond

Tags: android, json

I am trying to check some details from my JSON object but the problem is when I get the data from the JSON and comparing to another there is a problem that I cannot figure out.

I am trying to take the "status" (string of true / false) field from the JSON and compare to string of true string and then print another field from the JSON the problem is that it not enter into the if segment even though it need to true == true

**The JSON object -**

```
[
{
    "latitude":"33.33",
        "longitude":"44.44",
        "name":"test1",
        "Notification":"true",
        "status":"true"
},
{
    "latitude":null,
        "longitude":null,
        "name":null,
        "Notification":null,
        "status":"false"
}
]
```

---

```
        try {

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(answer);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length() - 1; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

            String a = jsonobject.getString("status"); // for the first is true and the second is false

            if(a == "true"){ // not enter to this if a equal to true
                Log.d("test",jsonobject.getString("status"));
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would be happy if someone can help me to understand what is the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: if(a.toString().equals("true")) try this

Comment: @ZakiPathan Thanks ! now it's work

Comment: and remove - 1 from for loop. if you want - 1 then put condition as i <= ksonarray.length() - 1

Comment: welcome bro. Happy to help :) :)

Comment: You should not compare Strings with equality operator, Instead of that you can compare like this `a.equals("true")` or `a.equalsIgnoreCase("true")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
   try {

    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(answer);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length() - 1; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

        String a = jsonobject.getString("status"); // for the first is true and the second is false

        if(a.equals("true")){ // not enter to this if a equal to true
            Log.d("test",jsonobject.getString("status"));
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please mark it correct so any one can use it in future.